# What should I do If I want to maintain session between HTTP and HTTPS - Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, session, ssl, https

What should I do If I want to maintain session between HTTP and HTTPS.. In my site's public area some pages are HTTP and some are HTTPS but I want to keep common session for both..

Comment: IF that's what you do, wouldn't that mean you're actually voiding any validity your https has?

Answer (score 2):

Once your user's have authenticated they will continue to have the same session cookie until it expires whether they are accessing pages with HTTP or HTTPS.  Make sure that you are using encryption on your session cookie to make it more difficult to crack if you are passing it over an insecure protocol.  You might want to look at the wikipedia article on [session hijacking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_hijacking) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of session state modes in ASP.NET you can use (which can be configured in web.config) apart from the default "In Proc":

**StateServer** mode, which stores session state in a separate process called the ASP.NET state service. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

**SQLServer** mode stores session state in a SQL Server database. This ensures that session state is preserved if the Web application is restarted and also makes session state available to multiple Web servers in a Web farm.

**Custom** mode, which enables you to specify a custom storage provider.

See [ASP.NET Session-State Modes on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178586.aspx). I haven't tested this for HTTPS, but hopefully StateServer or SQLServer should facilitate this.

Answer (score 0):

One session is maintained per application per user. So if you have one application which has some pages served over https and some over http, you do not have to worry about a new session being created when moving from https to http and vice-versa.